# Asynchronous calls in OpenCPU

Tags: r, opencpu

I would like to run OpenCPU job asynchronously and collect its results from a different session. In `Rserve` + `RSclient` I can do the following:

```
RS.eval(connection, expression, wait = FALSE)
# do something while the job is running
```

and then when I'm ready to receive results call either:

```
RS.collect(connection)
```

to try to collect results and wait until they are ready if job is still running or:

```
RS.collect(connection, timeout = 0)
```

if I want to check the job state and let it run if it is still not finished.

Is it possible with OpenCPU to receive the `tmp/*/...` path with the result id *before* the job has finished?

Comment: I think you want to do chaining (ocpu request inside an ocpu request).

Answer (score 1):

It seems acording to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544546/task-model-for-long-running-jobs-in-opencpu) that OpenCPU does not support asynchronous jobs. Every request between the browser and the OpenCPU server must be alive in order to execute a script or function and receive a response succesfully.
If you find any workaround I would be pleased to know it. 
In my case, I need to run a long process (may takes a few hours) and I can't keep alive the client request until the process finishes.

Comment: Did you find the solution for it? I had a look at https://github.com/joelkuiper/aplomb unfortunately the documentation is not in detail and unable to figure out how to use it.